Limit resuts returned by Spring Scroll Api
I want to implement the scroll API from Spring. So that when a user scrolls in the Front End, new data is loaded on every request from the Front end.
I try to limit the results returned by Spring and I am trying various ways.

PageRequest

    // Service
    fun getOrders(customerId: Long): List<OrderDto> {
        val customer = customerRepository.findById(customerId).getOrElse { return emptyList() }
        val orders: WindowIterator<Order> = WindowIterator.of<Order> { position ->
            orderRepsitory.findAllByCustomerOrderByCreated(
                 customer, 
                 position as KeysetScrollPosition?,
                 PageRequest.of(0, 20)
            )
        }
            .startingAt(ScrollPosition.keyset())
        val ordersResult: MutableList<Orders> = ArrayList<Orders>()
        orders.forEachRemaining { ordersResult.add(it) }
        return ordersResult.map {
            OrderDto(...)
        }
    }


    // Order Respository
    interface OrderRepository : JpaRepository<Order, Long> {
    fun findAllByCustomerOrderByCreated(
        customer: Customer, 
        position: KeysetScrollPosition?,
        pageable: Pageable,
        ): Window<Order>
    }

This always returns the whole table.

Adjust the JPA Query

    // Order Respository
    interface OrderRepository : JpaRepository<Order, Long> {
    fun findFirst5ByCustomerOrderByCreated(
        customer: Customer, 
        position: KeysetScrollPosition?,
        ): Window<Order>
    }


    // call to repository in service
    orderRepsitory.findFirst5ByCustomerOrderByCreated(
        customer, 
        position as KeysetScrollPosition?
    )

Same result, it returns the whole table.

Using Limit

    // Order Respository
    interface OrderRepository : JpaRepository<Order, Long> {
    fun findAllByCustomerOrderByCreated(
        customer: Customer, 
        limit: Limit,
        ): Window<Order>
    }

    // call to repository in service
    orderRepsitory.findAllByCustomerOrderByCreated(
        customer, 
        position as KeysetScrollPosition?,
         Limit.of(20)
    )

Same result, it returns the whole table.
How to limit the results with Spring Scroll API?

Which is what the WindowIterator does, you should only retrieve the window and iterate over that. You should be able to just return the Window as that is already either a Stream or Iterable itself. No need to put it in a list yourself.

@M.Deinum I am not sure if I understand you. Could you explain that with an example? I am pretty new to Spring/Kotlin and the learning curve is reather steep for me.

@M.Deinum when I look at this example https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/reference/data-commons/repositories/scrolling.html, the result is also limited by the query constructed through JPA query syntax...

Which uses Window not WindowIterator. The iterator will scroll over the windows.

@M.Deinum Hm, when I look at this example https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-scroll-api#2-scrolling-using-keyset-filtering as well as the code provided here https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/reference/data-commons/repositories/scrolling.html#repositories.scrolling.keyset it returns a Window from the repository function and a WindowIterator as a result wherever the repository is processed? But again, I am not very firm with Kotlin nor Spring, and just started learning. I probably miss something...

Third time is a charm remove the WindowIterator, return the Window. The sample is for scrolling, which means return all the results using windows (smaller portions). SO you are using the wrong section and tutorials for your usecase.

The "problem" is your use of the WindowIterator. This will keep iterating over successive Windows (which is the point of an iterator) until there is nothing more to retrieve.
So the problem isn't Spring Data, but rather your use of the WindowIterator. Just remove it and return the Window as is, or just use toList to convert it to a List.
fun getOrders(customerId: Long): List<OrderDto> {
    val customer = customerRepository.findById(customerId).getOrElse { return emptyList() }
    val orders = orderRepsitory.findAllByCustomerOrderByCreated(
             customer, 
             position as KeysetScrollPosition?,
             PageRequest.of(0, 20)
    return orders.toList()
    }
}


Where is position defined in your example?

Same place as it is in yours, this is your code, just stripped down from the WindowIterator.

In my code position is coming from the WindowIterator.of When you strip away the WindowIterator.of, there is no position coming from anywhere in my code. But I have the feeling I missunderstand what the Scrolling API is used for. Do I need to keep track of the position (hence: Send it via the request from the FE)?

Yes you need to keep track of it. That is basically what the PageRequest is doing. You need to remember the page which will result in the correct offset. The WindowIterator will iterate over all elements and automatically iterate over all, so yes you have a misunderstanding of wat scrolling is. The problem you have is that you are interating but stuffing it in a list. What you should do is return the itetor (or the window and do it youyrself). But the way you are using it will always retrieve all results.
